# How do you conditionally add a character string to certain values in a column?

Tags: r

I found that leading 0s had dropped from my data set at some point. Maybe someone had opened a CSV file and the leading 0s had fallen off or the data had been read in as an integer and the 0s had been removed. I'd been expecting all my `id`s to be 5 characters long and noticed an issue when some of them weren't.

TLDR: How do you conditionally add a string onto observations in a column?

Answer (score 1):

```
v <- c(1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111)

sprintf("%05d", v)

# [1] "00001" "00011" "00111" "01111" "11111"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share how to do this in case anyone runs into similar issues. This is useful to add leading 0s back into a data frame where they may have been dropped (E.G. loaded in as an integer data type, someone opened a CSV file and the 0s dropped, for example). In this case, I expected all of my IDs to be 5 digits long, so corrected for the conditionally dropped 0s. This solution has an emphasis on the tidyverse.

```
dataset <-
  dataset %>%
  mutate(id = as.character(id)) %>%
  mutate(id = case_when(nchar(id) == 4 ~ paste("0", id, sep =""), 
                         nchar(id) == 5~ id))
```